# Wordpress short codes display the codes itself not the elements

Tags: php, wordpress

I installed a carousel plugin which provided a short code for me to use

which is "wcf" before the gallery keyword , but unfortunately - no short codes works with me at all

- I tried to edit the home page - I used the text tab to insert the following codes

but this not work

```
[wcfgallery ids="149,148,147,146,145,144,138,132,133,139,140,141,135,136,142,143,137"]
```

this also not work

```
[gallery ids="149,148,147,146,145,144,138,132,133,139,140,141,135,136,142,143,137"]
```

it display the code itself on the page

[image]

Comment: did you installed it correctly? maybe compiler is missing, like visual composer is a compiler

Comment: its from text widget?

Comment: You put it directly on the code or in the editor ?

Comment: @AlexVand - in the text tab not the visual editor

Comment: Add your shortcode in "text-editor". And make sure your plugin activated properly.

Comment: Try to paste it in the visual editor

Comment: @ManishaVasani - Yes I actually add it in the text editor tab

Comment: @AlexVand it is the same - no difference

Comment: So you missed something else. Can you describe the step you've done in your question ? From the installation to the moment it don't work.

Comment: I edited the question - tried to provide info as much as I can

Comment: What does this have to do with WCF (Windows Communication Foundation)?

Comment: @Tim , thanks - I removed the tag

Answer (score 0):

Add this script in functions.php if you are using shortcode in text widget.

```
// Adding Shortcodes to the_excerpt() function
add_filter('the_excerpt', 'do_shortcode');

// Enable shortcodes in widgets
add_filter('widget_text', 'do_shortcode');
```

Replace `the_content()` to this `<?php echo apply_filters( 'the_content', $post->post_content ); ?>`

Comment: I copied your exact codes and pasted it in functions.php , unfortunately the same results

Comment: can you post your home page script?

Comment: where's this script ? - so I can copy it for you

Comment: I don't have a function called the_excerpt()

Comment: replace `the_content()` to this `<?php echo apply_filters( 'the_content', $post->post_content ); ?>` line number #20

Comment: unfortunately , the same results - the edits on this page "template-parts/content-page.php"

Comment: homepage is a template or default template?

Comment: I am not sure - I don't have a good experience with wordpress - anyway - I may detected my issue - it works when I add my short_code to custom html widget - but in text/visual editor will not work